# How Sending Invoice Email Works

Tags: magento2

I am facing a problem with the invoice email in magento 2. What is happening is that when I finalize an order, the payment confirmation email is already sent even though the payment is not confirmed. In the email box the customer immediately receives the email with the order details and the invoice email confirming the payment.

Could anyone help me understand what may be going on? Where should I start the analysis? In reality I would like to know exactly what happens at the back end at that moment, because unexpectedly my store is sending the invoice email when finishing the order.

If you have any tips for a young person just starting out in this Magento world, please tell me.

Thanks ...

Comment: what payment method are you using?

Comment: is a module for payment with bank slip, Brazilian standard. When enabling this payment method, what I mentioned happens. However, inside the module I didn't find anything that may be causing it. So the question to understand more generally.

Comment: try a different payment method to see what happens.

Comment: I was able to identify the problem in that module. When I disable the store it seems to work as it should. I still need to be able to understand in general these rules of sending email to propose a correction.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. By doing some research I was able to better understand what was happening. This issue helped me:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27656